# Override a method of an external object

Tags: java

I have a situation where i want to intercept/override a method of an external (i dont have access to them) object. An example of my situation:

I have an external object:

```
public class ExternalObject {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And an external class witch uses it:

```
public class ExternalClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExternalObject o = new ExternalObject();
        o.setName("Tom");

        MyClass.doSomething(o);

        o.setName("Jerry");

        System.out.print(o.getName());
    }
}
```

And then there is MyClass witch has an oppertunity to acces the external object:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void doSomething(ExternalObject o){

    }
}
```

Is it possible to overwrite or modify the setName method in MyClass?
What i need is for the setName method to check if the name is "jerry" then change it back to "tom" and if not then do what original method does.

Something like this:

```
public void mySetName(String name){
  if(name.equals("Jerry"){
    name = "Tom";
  }
  doWhatOriginalMethodDoes();
}
```

So if someone runs the external class like it is now then Tom will be printed out two times.

The external (original) object and method is quite complex by the way. 
I have searched around and this should be possible to do with reflect.Proxy but i cant get it to work.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Why can't you create a subclass and override the method?

Comment: You can't override methods of _objects_. You can override methods of _classes_, by extending them.

Comment: You can override the method of the class as long as the method is not private nor final.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to use inheritance:

```
public class MySubClass extends ExternalObject {

    private ExternalObject obj;

    public MySubClass(ExternalObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name){
        if(name.equals("Jerry") {
            super.setName("Tom");
        } else {
            super.setName(name);
        }
    }

    // override all public method to call super method
    @Override
    public AClass otherMethod1(BClass arg){
        return super.otherMethod1(arg);
    }

    @Override
    public CClass otherMethod2(DClass arg){
        return super.otherMethod2(arg);
    }
}
```

And as MySubClass is a ExternalObject, you can call:

```
MySubClass subObject = new MySubClass(o);
MyClass.doSomething(subObject);
```

---

Or, if your class implements an interface you can use a Proxy:

First, define a InvocationHandler

```
public Class ExternalObjectInterfaceInvocationHandler implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

    // keep a reference to the wrapped object
    private ExternalObjectInterface obj;

    public ExternalObjectInterfaceInvocationHandler(ExternalObjectInterface obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (m.getName().equals("setName")) {
                // do something
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        // return something
    }
}
```

Then wrap your object with the proxy:

```
ExternalObjectInterface obj = ...

//wrap the obj with a proxy
ExternalObjectInterface wrappedInstance = (ExternalObjectInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    ExternalObjectInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
    new Class[] {ExternalObjectInterface.class},
    new ExternalObjectInterfaceHandler(  obj  )
);
```

And then call:

```
MyClass.doSomething(wrappedInstance);
```

---

Third solution if your object do not implement an interface, is to use CGLib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To wrap your object you can use something like this:

```
public static <S,W> W createWrapper(final S source, final Class<W> wrapperClass) {

    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(wrapperClass);
    enhancer.setInterfaces(wrapperClass.getInterfaces());
    enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {

        public Object intercept(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {

            if ("setName".equals(method.getName())) {
                //do something
                return null;
            }

            if (Arrays.asList(wrapperClass.getDeclaredMethods()).contains(method)) {
                return methodProxy.invokeSuper(proxy, args);
            }

            return methodProxy.invoke(source, args);
        }
    });

    return (W) enhancer.create();
}
```

Some examples of using CGLib [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java) or [here](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2005.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a part of the standard Java API. The only real need for that it may be testing such "external objects", or very corner cases when you need to "extend" the final classes from the third party library. Normally, you just create and use the derived class.

The functionality you request is provided by mocking frameworks like [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/be6d53f62790ac7c9cf07c32485343ce94e1b563/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2). They allow to replace the method implementations ("stubbing") or monitor calls of the actually existing methods ("spying"). Normally, these frameworks are used for testing. I have never heard anybody using them in production but might be possible if you cannot find another workaround.

If the "external object" can be represented as an interface, another approach would be to create and use a [proxy class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). However proxy can only substitute an interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the creation of the object, then the only way that comes to my mind is to replace the class with your own subclass using instrumentation and a java agent. It will be a little ugly, but it will work (as long as the class is not already loaded at the time your agent code runs).

I would use javassist to create your replacement class, and then register a ClassFileTransformer for that class.

References can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a subclass and use that. It's a lot easier to write, use, and understand versus reflection.

```
public class MyExternalObject extends ExternalObject {
    @Override
    public void mySetName(String name){
        if(name.equals("Jerry")
            name = "Tom";
        else
            this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: but this would require you to modify `ExternalClass` to use this sublcass, which I didn't assume would be possible because of the naming description, 'External'

Comment: You wouldn't modify `ExternalClass`, you'd write your own subclass.

Comment: Your own subclass of `ExternalClass`? isn't this circumventing the question?

Comment: @haventchecked No, in Java this would be the proper way to get the behavior the asker mentioned.

Comment: This setName method was an simple example. Like i wrote the real method is quite complex and i cant override it, i have to use the functionality of the real method. (in my example doWhatOriginalMethodDoes()). So this wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

ExternalObject.java:

```
public class ExternalObject {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

ExternalClass.java:

```
public class ExternalClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExternalObject object = new ExternalObject();
        object.setName("tom");
        System.out.println(object.getName());
        MyClass.doSomeThing("jerry");
    }

}
```

and MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void doSomeThing(String name) {
        ExternalObject object = new ExternalObject() {
            @Override
            public void setName(String name) {
                if (name.equals("jerry")) {
                    super.setName("tom");
                } else {
                    super.setName(name);
                }
            }
        };
        object.setName(name);
        System.out.println(object.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: @user1985273 was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You should just implement code in your `myclass` to perform the required action( you can call it as pre-processing) and then pass the value to the `setname` method, based on the result of your pre-processing.